# Flashcard webapp: want to load a deck to study based on the deck selected

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I am working on a flashcards app using flask. It is similar to Anki if you know about that. When I click on a deck, I want it to go to study_session.html where it displays the first card of the selected deck. Currently I have a home screen that lists the user's decks. Each list item is a button element with an onclick attribute that calls a javascript method that takes the selected deck's name as a parameter. The method sends a post request to the flask route "/study-session" along with the name of the deck. This allows the route's method to get the selected deck and send the appropriate flashcard to the "study_session.html" page to be displayed. What's wrong is that either the javascript method or the server-side route method, or both do not seem to be executing. When I click the deck I want to study, nothing happens. I would like someone to point out my mistake and offer the appropriate fix. If I need ajax, please show me how the javascript would look like. Thank you.

Here is the html that has the button with an onclick attribute:

```
{% for deck in user.decks %}
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <button class="btn btn-link pl-0" onclick="startStudySession({{ deck.deck_name }})">{{deck.deck_name}}</button>
```

Here is the javascript:

```
// Takes deckId and sends post req to study-session route.
// Then runs study-session view
function startStudySession(deckName) {
    // Specify what route to send request to
    fetch("/study-session", {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({deckName: deckName})
    }).then((_res) => {
        window.location.href = "/study-session"
    });
}
```

Here is the route method on the python server:

```
@views.route('/study-session', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def study_session():
    """
    Renders study_session page with one flashcard displayed. Handles all requests on study_session page.
    """
    request_data = json.loads(request.data)
    cur_deck = current_user.get_deck(request_data['deckName'])
    cur_card = cur_deck.notes[0].flashcards[0]
    front = cur_card.front_text
    back = cur_card.back_text
    print("is this working?")
    return jsonify('', render_template("study_session.html", user=current_user, front=front, back=back))
```

Comment: Could you share the Anki  link?

Comment: https://ankiweb.net/about
You'll have to make an account to see what it looks like.